# elasticsearch query for GCP alpha and beta api's

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform

trying to get this query below to work on GCP.  need this to query for beta api's being used every 24 hours.  keep getting error in the query.  probably a simple syntax error, but im not seeing it.

```
    GET /gcp-%2A/_search
{
    "query": {
          "range" : {
            "timestamp" : {
                "gte" : "now-1d/d",
                "lt" :  "now/d"
            }
        },
            "wildcard": {
            "protoPayload.methodName": {
                "value": "*beta*",
                "boost": 1.0,
                "rewrite": "constant_score"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "[range] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
        "line": 9,
        "col": 13
      }
    ],
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "[range] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
    "line": 9,
    "col": 13
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
GET /gcp-%2A/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": "now-1d/d",
              "lt": "now/d"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "protoPayload.methodName": {
              "value": "*beta*",
              "boost": 1,
              "rewrite": "constant_score"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if i wanted to search for alpha and beta in this query what modification could be made?

Comment: alpha `AND` beta or `OR`?